# Django Heroku APScheduler Scrapy

Tags: python, django, heroku, scrapy, apscheduler

I have got a basic Django web application running on Heroku. I would like to add a spider to crawl some webs (e.g with [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)) based on a scheduled task ( e.g. via [APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/v2.1.2/) ) to get some tables of Django databases loaded with collected data.

Does anybody know of documentation or examples for the basis to achieve this kind of integration? I find it very hard to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used **Scrapy** at all, but I'm actually working with **APScheduler** and it's very simple to use. So my first guess would be to use a **BackgroundScheduler** (inside your **Django** app) and add a job to it that would execute a callable "*spider*" periodically.

The thing here is how could you embed a **Scrapy** project inside your **Django** app so you can access one of its "*spiders*" and effectively use it as a callable in your scheduled job.

I'm maybe not helping much, but I'm just trying to give you some kickstart orientation. I'm pretty sure that if you carefully read the **Scrapy's** documentation you'll make your way.

Best.

Comment: Yep, BackgroundScheduler is usually the way to go.

Comment: Vote up my answer :)! haha you're welcome, glad to help a little bit at least!.

Comment: Hi, could you tell if can add the BackgroudSceduler at my wsgi.py?

Comment: I'm not sure @JoabMendes, wish I could be of more help